# Cannot type backslash in bash on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: bash, command-line, keyboard, macos

I can't type the backslash `\` in Bash. I have Mac OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5.

I already tried <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> and it also doesn't work.

If any one know or heard on this problem before?

Comment: can you type it somewhere else? (why the [linux] tag if it's about Mac)

Comment: This sounds like it *could* be something wrong with your .inputrc file.  That's just a guess though.

Comment: @ilkkachu I can type anywhere else except in the bash

Comment: Of possible relevance: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/42027/cannot-insert-backslash-with-bash-python-works-fine-with-csh-idle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42027/cannot-insert-backslash-with-bash-python-works-fine-with-csh-idle)

Comment: @PhilipCouling This is my also idea. have you any suggestions how to deal with it?

Comment: @user454461 my idea was the [answer posted by marshki](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42027/cannot-insert-backslash-with-bash-python-works-fine-with-csh-idle).  I knew I'd seen it somewhere but couldn't track down the link.  At the very least check if you have an `~/.inputrc` file and if you are still stuck you can [edit] your question to show what you have in it.